# Not able to start my webex on ubuntu

Tags: dependencies, webex

Im not able to start webex on ubuntu . Every time i try to start it i get an error called libcurl.so not found .

The error looks something like this 
Can't load libcurl,so:no libcurl.so found

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands in Terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libcurl3:i386
```

<sub>Source: Google and guesswork. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/mshkrebtan/407786e334847544b40e7d6a8a53d247) confirmed what I thought.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Running `apt-cache search libcurl` shows 43 entries. You should install one of:

```
libcurl3 - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
libcurl3-dbg - debugging symbols for libcurl (OpenSSL, GnuTLS and NSS flavours)
libcurl3-gnutls - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
libcurl3-nss - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (NSS flavour)
libcurl4-doc - documentation for libcurl
libcurl4-gnutls-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS flavour)
libcurl4-nss-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (NSS flavour)
libcurl4-openssl-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavour)
```